# How to save foreach to variable in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, database, laravel, variables

I want to display these elements:

- `$category->getFullNameAttribute()`
- `$category->id`
- `$category->email`
- `$category->image`

Here is my view:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card" style="padding: 20px; overflow: auto;">
        <ul id="ul-data" style="display:none;">
            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                <li class="user-{{ $category->id }}">
                    {{ $category->getFullNameAttribute() }}
                    {{ $category->id }}
                    {{ $category->email }}
                    {{ $category->image }}
                    {{-- {{$category->representative}} --}}
                    @if (count($category->childes))
                        @include('management.orgchart.manageChild',['childs' => $category->childes])
                    @endif
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
        <div id="chart-container"></div>
```

However, when I display them in this way they are all going into the same div title or text.

I am getting big problems because I need it separate into more div because I want to display email at the bottom, the name at the top, id next to image and various other styling choices.

Does anyone know how I can put elements (id, email, image...) into different variables so I can easily manipulate them.

I appreciate your help and I will do everything to fix issues.
If I didn't explain something properly please ask me in comments and I will try my best to explain it in more detail.

Edit: This is controller for that method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class OrgController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Display the OrgChart.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        Carbon::setLocale(App::getLocale());

        if (Session::get('locked') === true) {
            return redirect('/lock');
        }

        $categories = User::where('supervisor_id', '=', null)->get();
        return view('management.orgchart.index', compact('categories'));
    }
}
```

This is the model window which appears when pressing the right title of the names.
I want to put data into this div (first name, last name, email etc...):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Profile Window</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <div class="img-container">
                        <img src="img/default-avatar.png" class="img-circle" id="circleImage" alt="Cinque Terre" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <div id="first_name" style="display: inline-block;">First name</div> <br>
                    <div id="last_name" style="display: inline-block;">Last name</div>
                    <div id="birthday">00.10.2020</div>
                    <div id="customer_email">hello@k-tronik.de</div>
                    <div id="representative_id">Representive Person</div>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <p id="contentWin">
                    {{-- @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <li class="user-{{ $user->id }}">
                            {{ $user->getId }}
                            @if (count($user->childes))
                                @include('management.orgchart.manageChild',['childs' => $category->childes])
                            @endif
                        </li>
                    @endforeach --}}
                    Using dummy content or fake information in the Web design process can result in products with unrealistic assumptions and potentially serious design flaws. A seemingly elegant design can quickly begin to bloat with unexpected content or break under the weight of actual activity. Fake data can ensure a nice looking layout but it doesn’t reflect what a
                    Lorem Ipsum actually is usefull in the design stage as it
                    Kyle Fiedler from the Design Informer feels that distracting copy is your fault:
                    If the copy becomes distracting in the design then you are doquestions about lorem ipsum don’t.
                    Summing up, if the copy is diverting attention from the design it’s because it’s not up to task.
                    Typographers of yore didn't come up with the concept ot on it. They will be drawn to it, fiercely. Do it the wrong way and draft copy can derail your design review.
                    Asking the client to pay no attention Lorem Ipsum ing you can't win. Whenever draft copy comes up in a meeting confused questions about it ensue.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                {{--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>--}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upload your controller method as well  and explain what kind of div you want to show your result

Comment: Why would you want the values in variables? They are dynamic.. Just add divs in your for loop surrounding the corrosponding data

Comment: @Tomm , I have modal window that will popup and i don't know how i can reference this to div into modal window ( i don't need it to make it here ) I mean i don't know how i can edit other div.. 

 Where i can find that controller ?
I want to show informations from the elements above into normal html div like this one just to display informations on popup window ...
example of div: <div id="first_name" style="display: inline-block;">First name</div>

Comment: @Md.JubairMizan , 
I have made a new edit and add a controller to this post . I hope you have some solution

Comment: I am finding it very hard to understand what you mean

Comment: should be ` $categories = User::whereNull('supervisor_id')->get();`

Comment: @Tom,
I try to show this element from foreach loop  {{$category->email}} to the model window popup into html div this ---> <div id="customer_email">hello@k-tronik.de</div>

I don't have idea how it need to be done .. I hope you now understand what i mean..If you don't understand please tell me i will explain again and do my best..

Comment: @ČikaTuna Did you want single row result or many row . If you want to single row result then you should to use `first()` instead of `get()`

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan, 
I want to populate model window into many rows because i have like 10 people which i want to display their informations when you click on their name in popup windows , so i want to display email , first name, last name, birthday etc.. and I need many rows now when i try to display i am getting all into same row because they go to the title..

Comment: Also, FWIW, when using an accessor: you don't have to reference the method on the model. You can simply write `$category->full_name ` instead of  `$category->getFullNameAttribute()`

Comment: @JustCarty, 
I didn't wrote that also I want to know where I can find that method if you know it will help me :)) 
I hope someone will know solution for my problem so I can make it as soon as possible.

Comment: I suggest migrating this to the client-side using e.g. react or Vue (or similar). The problem here is you're statically rendering HTML on the server side and want to display a dynamic modal determined at runtime. You can only do this using JavaScript. Yes, in theory, you could store information on the element as `data-*` attributes but that's just manually implementing what MVVM frameworks already do

Comment: @apokryfos , 
Do you know how I can make it client sided with vue or something because that is really new to me and I don't know how i can implement it. Any example or something ? because i really don't know where to start. Btw; thank you for your suggestion . I will try my best to find solution.

Comment: I think the place to start if you've not used anything like this before is Vue.js. There's some [scaffolding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/frontend) that ships with Laravel and more documentation along with a tutorial can be found in the [vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/) it can be daunting at first but once you get more familiar it will make it much easier to make interactive web applications.

Comment: Yes but I need to fix this today and I can not find in this documentation example for my issue. I hope you will help me with some example code.. if possible :/

Answer (score 0):

This might help you,

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="card" style="padding: 20px; overflow: auto;">
    <ul id="ul-data" style="display:none;">
        @foreach($categories as $category)
            <li class="user-{{ $category->id }}">
                <span class="getFullNameAttribute">
                    {{ $category->getFullNameAttribute()}}
                </span>
                <span class="id">
                    {{ $category->id}}
                </span>
                <span class="email">
                    {{$category->email}}
                </span>
                <span class="image">
                    {{$category->image}}
                </span>
                <span class="representative">
                    {{--{{$category->representative}}--}}
                </span>
                @if(count($category->childes))
                    @include('management.orgchart.manageChild',['childs' => $category->childes])
                @endif
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    <div id="chart-container"></div>
</div>
```

You can change markup according to your needs,
and if you want to assign single category variable to other variable you can do this,

```
@php
    $your_variable = $category;
@endphp
```